# Alternative way of finding a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**The problem:**

Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. $U$ is given by the span of the vectors $\begin{Bmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-3\\3\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\\-4\\-2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-3\\-1\\-3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-3\\1\\-3\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}$.

I need to find a basis of $U$.

**My attempt:**
I wrote the vectors into a matrix *horizontally* like this:

$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&-2\\1&-3&3&-1\\-2&0&-4&-2\\-1&-3&-1&-3\\1&-3&1&-3\end{pmatrix}$

Here, I tried to find linear combinations and was able to reduce the vectors down to the form:

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

This leaves me with a basis for $U$ as follows: $B = \begin{Bmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}$.

By definition, a basis of a vector space is a set of linearly independent vectors, which span the vector space (in this example $U$). Since this is the case, $B$ is a basis for $U$.

Is my reasoning correct? If so, please let me know if there is a more standard way of writing down this procedure.

Comment: Good job, there are no mistakes. Just one remark in order to make the exercise quicker. Since $\dim(\mathbb{R}^4)=4$  every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ has dimension $\leq 4$ and so, since $U$ is given by the span of $5$ vectors you can eliminate one of the vectors  before doing any computations.

Comment: @Marcos makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Marcos You can't just eliminate any vector though, you have to eliminate one that is in the span of the others.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of solving this problem is to leave the five vectors listed from top to bottom, that is, as columns of $4 \times 5$ matrix.  Then use Gauss-Jordan elimination in the standard way.  At the end, the independent vectors (from the original set) are the ones that correspond to leading $1$'s in the (reduced) row echelon from.

Applying this, the reduce row echelon form is

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0.5 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 && 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 1 && 0.5 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, a basis for the space spanned by the $5$ vectors is the set of the first $3$ vectors.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this way around a few sites, but it was not really intuitive for me, hence my question. Is there any advantage in solving it the standard way when it doesn't matter which vectors are forming the basis in the end?

Comment: I think if you list the vectors as rows, some mix-up may occur if you switch two rows.